# How to edit retrieved data from database and return table's data to the form's text fields

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I am unable to edit the retrieved table rows from my database (MySQL), when I press on the edit pencil I get nothing in my form, but for delete it works successfully at any row I want.

[image: screenshot of my table row]
Here is the `history.scala.html` file where I get table data

```
@(formList: List[Users],form: Form[Users])

@main("history") {

   @for(i <- mtnUsers.all()) {

      @if(i.client.equalsIgnoreCase("potato")) {
         <table>
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td> <a href="/#"><i>@i.firstname @i.lastname </i></a></td>
                  <td> <a href="/#"><i>@i.phonenumber</i></a></td>
                  <td> <a href="/#"><i>@i.amount</i></a></td>
                  <td> <a href="/#"><i>@i.doneAt</i></a></td>
                  <td> <a href="@routes.Application.edit(i.id)"><i><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></i></a></td>
                  <td> <a href="@routes.Application.delete(i.id)"><i><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></i></a></td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      }
   }
}
```

The following is my controller methods of edit and the one of retrieving

```
public static Result history(long id) {
   Form<Users> taskData = form(Users.class);
   return ok(history.render(Users.MTN(), taskData));
}

public static Result edit(Long id) {
   Form<Users> content = form(Users.class).fill(
   Users.find.byId(id));

   return ok(views.html.edit.render(id,content));
}

public static Result update(Long id) {
   Form<Users> updateForm = form(Users.class).bindFromRequest();
   if (updateForm.hasErrors()) {
      return badRequest(edit.render(id, updateForm));
   }
   updateForm.get().update(id);

   return redirect(routes.Application.profile());
}
```

And `edit.scala.html`, the form that should get data to be modified

```
<form action="@routes.Application.update(id)" method="post">

   <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Phone Number</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input name="phonenumber" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">First Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input name="firstname" id="firstname" minValue="2" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Last Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input name="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">User</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <select class="form-control" name="client" id="client" value="client">
            <option value="select">select ..</option>
            <option value="potato">potato</option>
            <option value="kamagaju">kamagaju</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Amount</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input name="amount" id="" value="" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Rwfr">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="panel-footer">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Send">
      <input type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="Reset">
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What i noticed everything is working very fine, i mean edit and update any row of mysql table. only one issue i stay with is how to get some text value in edit text after pressing the pencil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i did finally is to add the following scripts marked in bold in my edit.scala.html template. and in each edit text value i added :

**value="@data.id_of_this_filed"**

```
  @(data:Users,customerForm: Form[Users])

@main("edit") {

   <form ... >

.....

<div class="form-group row  ">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Amount</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input
                                            name="amount"
                                            id=""
                                            **value="@data.amount"**
                                            class="form-control"
                                            type="number"
                                            placeholder="Rwfr">
                                </div>
                            </div>

.......

   </form>
        }
```